# the meaning of 'slope up"

Tags: idioms

> When Mark first showed himself at the cardinal’s door, he **sloped
>   up** in patched boots and a canvas doublet that had belonged to a
>   bigger man.
>
> *Bring Up the Bodies by Hilary Mantel*

What does 'slope up" mean here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally **slope up** should mean:

> **slope up (to something)**
>   to slant upward in the direction of something.
>
> *> The ramp sloped up to the door, allowing wheelchairs to enter. It
>   sloped up rather steeply.*

[Source](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/slope+up)

But here, in this context, I think this below-mentioned meaning will hold up:

> **slope**:
>
> To move or walk:
>
> *"Without another word he turned and sloped off down the driveway" (Roald Dahl).*

[Source](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sloped)